# What's the difference between AngularJS Material and Polymer?

Tags: angularjs, polymer, angularjs-material

I see many material elements both in [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) and [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org). As I know, both of them are google's products about Material design, Are there any relationships between them? Are there any plans for Material for Angular v2?

Comment: To my knowledge there are three implementation of Material design for web by google: Polymer, Polymer.dart and AngularJS teams. I'm sure that somebody will develop set for AngularJS 2.0, because why not :)

Comment: And I found the post in the google forum. <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/polymer-dev/fAvqDo40tMk/v3dLso5b-VYJ>.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Material design is a new design language [spec](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) that many frameworks, widget libraries, and 3rd authors can adopt and implement.

- Polymer is *the* reference implementation of material design for the web. As an added bonus, turns out web components lend themselves extremely well to the design/patterns of material design (css scoping, compartmentalization, declarative, etc.)
- Polymer.dart is simply a Dart port of Polymer. Since it's a port, the `paper-*` (material design) elements should be very similar to their JS counterparts. Ideally, there would be no port of the elements themselves, but true dart/js interop is lacking right now.
- Angular has their own interpretation of the [material design spec](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). Not sure how closely it adheres to the spec.